# How to update SQL Server database column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table called `Table1` that looks something like this :

```
MEID  Type
KELO  mb
OLEM  mb-sd
```

And another table called `Table2`:

```
MEID  SD
KELO  NO
OLEM  YES
```

I'm updating Table2 SD column like this :

```
UPDATE Table2 
SET SD = (CASE 
              WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                           FROM Table1 
                           WHERE Table1.MEID = Table2.MEID AND Table1.[Type] LIKE '%sd') 
                  THEN 'YES'  
                  ELSE 'NO' 
          END)
```

I'm just wondering how can I update `Table2` `SD` column if the `ID` is no longer `"mb-sd"` in `Table1` the next day.

For example :

```
MEID  Type
KELO  mb
OLEM  mb
```

```
MEID   SD
KELO  NO
OLEM  NO
```

It sound easy but I still couldn't figure out yet so any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Use a `VIEW` instead, then query the `VIEW`. Don't store data that is meant to reflect data that appears in another table that then needs to *change* every time the other table changes.

Comment: The `UPDATE` query that you have provided above should be able to take care of that use case too, you can try a sample on another table by creating dummy values

Comment: Instead of updating that other table, create a query or view that returns the current results. The UPDATE can be simplified a lot but you'll always have issues with stale data.

Comment: your problem is that the query will check if any row id like 121 has a type sd,

Comment: What are you trying to do anyway? If you care about `-sd` it means that column is really *two* columns stored in a single location. That's very bad and very, very slow. You can't use indexes when searching for *suffixes*. The server has to search the entire table to find matches

Comment: Agreed, it sounds like your table needs to be redesigned to have more columns

Comment: You could create a persisted computed column in *Table1* based on the contents of `Type`, eg `IsSD AS IIF(Type LIKE '%sd','YES','NI') PERSISTED`. Such a column would be updated automatically. This way you wouldn't have to perform any updates or even calculate the value on the fly.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, as [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76220049/how-to-update-sql-server-database-column#comment134412474_76220049) by [Panagiotis Kanavos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/134204/panagiotis-kanavos), it appears that your design is denormalised here. Instead of `Type` having a value like `'mb-sd'`, you should have 2 rows with the values `'mb'` and `'sd'`.

As I [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76220049/how-to-update-sql-server-database-column#comment134412418_76220049) in the comments, this isn't something you should be storing in your database; use a `VIEW` (or perhaps a parametrised inline table value function) for something like this. Storing data in a table that needs to change every time a value in *another* table changes is almost always a bad idea; it normally involves `TRIGGER`s which can get expensive quickly. if you use something like a `VIEW` then the data only needs to be determined at the time you query that, and there's no need to constantly `UPDATE` your table.

As we only have two tables here, and latter appears to be the same table as the first with a yes/no, I'm going to switch to a single table. I also demonstrate how you could see if both `md` or `sd` appear in the table, as I suspect that is a follow on question.

I also, however, normallise your data, which is something you should be doing:

```sql
--Create sample table
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable (MEID varchar(4),
                            Type varchar(2));
--Sample data
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (MEID, Type)
VALUES('KELO','sd'),
      ('OLEM','md'),
      ('OLEM','sd');
GO

--Create View
CREATE VIEW dbo.YourView AS

    SELECT MEID,
           CASE COUNT(CASE Type WHEN 'md' THEN 1 END) WHEN 0 THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END AS md,
           CASE COUNT(CASE Type WHEN 'sd' THEN 1 END) WHEN 0 THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END AS sd
    FROM dbo.YourTable
    GROUP BY MEID;
GO

--Query view
SELECT MEID,
       sd,
       md
FROM dbo.YourView;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/aLYCuiT7)